# creating Cloud page web app

Tags: marketing-cloud

Hi New to Marketing cloud,

started building cloud page web app with forms and post processing. I have started using  Amp scripting/SSJS.

My first questions is about Securing cloud Pages.  I realise that they are open with no  restrictions once published. My solution has been to implment IP  client check ( all pages)  & password protect page  for a web form. This works. Are there more secure ways to do this in Cloud pages?

Second I see that from the marketing Cloud Development center a variety of  SDK's.  Should I be using other marketing cloud software development tools to build web apps in Cloud pages or just stick with the approach of using AMP scripting /SSJS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Cloud Page securing there aren't that many features that come with Marketing Cloud, so the easiest is just to treat is as a regular site that is hosted elsewhere.

Although it will depend on the purpose of this web-app. In case its for your Marketing Cloud contacts, then you can utilize the Contact model to use some attributes as security checks and PURL's, meaning if certain attribute value is missing or not what expected, a redirect could happen.

Under CloudPage configuration / [**Advanced Settings**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_page_details_and_advanced_settings.htm&type=5) you can also make sure the webcrawlers wouldn't be able to index the site and follow links on it. 
 It is also possible to purchase [**SSL certificate**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232477&type=1) for the Cloud Pages.

Overall just stick to the AMPscript/SSJS, there's no need to for any SDK's for regular Cloud Page development if it's not doing anything with other Studios directly.

Comment: +1 It is good to understand the SFMC SOAP API options and methods.  You'll need them in writing your AMPscript or SSJS.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't noticed the Advanced options a) Do not allow search engines to view this page & b)Do not allow search engines to follow links on this page. I will use accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but Mateusz Dąbrowski has described a few very neat ways of securing CloudPages, thus allowing to create internal CloudPage apps:

https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/ssjs/snippets/sfmc-cloud-page-apps/
https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/webinars/sfmc-webinar-cloud-page-apps/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.